# Django rest api send email return value true but email isnt sent

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, smtp, ovh

I'm trying to send the token to reset password on my django application, the post return a confirmation that the email is sent but, no email has been sent. here are my settings and config

settings :

```
EMAIL_BACKEND ='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_PORT = os.getenv('EMAIL_PORT')
EMAIL_USE_TLS = os.getenv('EMAIL_USE_TLS')
EMAIL_HOST = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST')
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = os.getenv('DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL')
```

.env :

```
  EMAIL_BACKEND="django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
    EMAIL_PORT=465
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
    EMAIL_HOST="ssl0.ovh.net"
    EMAIL_HOST_USER=""
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=""
    DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL=EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

signals.py:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives, send_mail
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.urls import reverse
from ndgd.settings import EMAIL_HOST_USER
from django_rest_passwordreset.signals import reset_password_token_created
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes

@receiver(reset_password_token_created)
def password_reset_token_created(sender, instance, reset_password_token, *args, **kwargs):
    
    context = {
        'current_user': reset_password_token.user,
        'username': reset_password_token.user.username,
        'email': reset_password_token.user.email,
        'reset_password_url':"{}?token={}".format(
            instance.request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('password_reset:reset-password-confirm')),
            reset_password_token.key)
    }

    # Email
    email_html_message = render_to_string('templates/email/password_reset.email.html', context)
    email_plaintext_message = render_to_string('templates/email/password_reset_email.txt', context)

    ms = EmailMultiAlternatives(
        "Password Reset".format(title = "Nouvelles Donnes"),
        email_plaintext_message,
        EMAIL_HOST_USER,
        [reset_password_token.user.email]
    )

    print(EMAIL_HOST_USER)
    print(reset_password_token.user.email)
    ms.attach_alternative(email_html_message, "text/html")
    ms.send
```

this is the postman return value but the email is never received i need help.
thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was two issues first : like the answer above i had to change `ms.send` to `ms.send()`,

Which raised another issue. for using `EMAIL_PORT=465` i had to change  `EMAIL_USE_TLS = True` to `EMAIL_USE_SSL = True`

Answer (score 2):

Here not calling `.send()` function of email send, it's making only object of `.send` function need to be called with parentheses

```py
ms.attach_alternative(email_html_message, "text/html")
ms.send()   # need to call
```